# Apache Commons-Config - ClearTree() leaves whitespace in document

Tags: java, xml, xpath, whitespace, apache-commons-config

This is probably a silly one, but when using the clearTree() function on a HierarchicalConfiguration node it leaves the newline in after each property. Note they are the single line kind like

```
<parent>
     <element name="blahblah" />
     <element name="blahblah2" />
</parent>
```

so a  node.clearTree("parent"); will basically leave behind two new lines in place of the elements.

I am essentially using it to clear out old properties, then update them with new values. As this operation can happen semi frequently over time, the file can quite possibly have a lot of newlines in it and is growing out like so:

```
<parent>
     <element name="blahblah" />
     <element name="blahblah2" />











</parent>
```

Overall it is not a big deal, just over time I can foresee it being a problem. Is there anyway to clear out a HierarchicalConfiguration's elements and clean up the whitespace? Or perhaps just an another xpath clear that will take out the white space added?